# Turkish Characters not supported by BDE Delphi 5

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-5, bde

We have a legacy application that has been built in Delphi 5 using SQL Server for data storage. It uses BDE components for all database operations. This application has to now support Turkish characters. For which, the database part of the problem was taken care of by using the collation 'Turkish_100_CI_AS'. But, the application (or rather BDE) does not support turkish characters when trying to logon to the server. Tried the LANGDRIVER property for MSSQL driver and saw that there no drivers available for SQL-with-Turkish. Where should I be looking if I want to login to my application for a user whose login name has Turkish characters?

Comment: Keep in mind, you're going to have waaaay more issues than just your database connection. The entire VCL is pre-unicode in Delphi 5. Expect the UI to show garbage data everywhere. To make things easy, you should seriously consider upgrading to one of the later versions of Delphi, where unicode is enforced. Otherwise, there's a good chance you may need to use third-party controls to handle these characters.

Comment: Surprisingly, there seems to be no issues we've seen with the UI components. Once we deployed the Application on an Turkish OS, the controls all seemed to worked perfectly since each form inherits the character set based on the system locale. So, no issues with those. But, this login is where we are currently stuck without a way out. 

The code is able perfectly store the Turkish characters in the String/WideString variables. But, the moment we do a TDatabase.Open, it comes back with 'Login failed for user abc' and abc has garbage values for Turkish characters.

Comment: Ahh, if the Windows language is Turkish, then yes. I've never had any experience with changing OS language, so I didn't think of that. The problem I described presumably comes when mixing languages.

Comment: In that case, I wish you luck finding drivers you can use with BDE. It's been deprecated for over a decade. Which comes back to the option of upgrading.

Comment: Are there any other drivers apart from the ones that come with the installation? Is there a package for a Turkish Driver I could download from somewhere? or what minimal code change you think I can do to bypass this?

Comment: Back when Delphi 5 was released, I'm sure there were plenty. But those things disappear over this long of time.

Comment: Prevent them from using native characters for their login name. Force email for instance.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz For login name, perhaps. What about the password?

Comment: @Jerry - It may work actually, the same garbage gets stored and compared. But I'd suggest advising against using them anyway.

Comment: @Sertac True, in the end, regardless of what character set was used, it still uses the same data behind the scenes anyway. The concern would only be with display, which there's never a reason to display a password.